# How do you use inline code to set the value of a checkbox

Tags: html, asp.net, checkbox, inline-code

I have a list of checkboxes that get created dynamically in a loop and when I try to set the value with inline-code, it just gives me the inline code without evaluating it.  Here is an example:

```
<ul>
   <%
    string testValue = string.Empty;
    for(int index = 0; index < 5; index++)
    {
        testValue = "blah" + index;
     %>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" runat="server" value="<%= testValue %>" />
        </li>
    <%
    }
     %>
</ul>
```

and here is the output I'm getting:

```
<ul>        
<li>
   <input name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl00" type="checkbox" value="&lt;%= testValue %>" />
</li>

<li>
    <input name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl00" type="checkbox" value="&lt;%= testValue %>" />
</li>

<li>
     <input name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl00" type="checkbox" value="&lt;%= testValue %>" />
</li>

<li>
      <input name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl00" type="checkbox" value="&lt;%= testValue %>" />
</li>

<li>
      <input name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl00" type="checkbox" value="&lt;%= testValue %>" />
</li>
</ul>
```

Can someone PLEASE help me with this?

Comment: I think you need to use single quotes on `value="<%= testValue %>"`

Comment: get rid of `runat="server"` unless you need the check boxes to be a server controls

Comment: If I try single quotes value='<%= testValue %>" I get the same result: <input name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl00" type="checkbox" value="&lt;%= testValue %>" />

Comment: Whoops didn't notice the `runat="server"`, I wrote it on my end and it was working, because I din't have that set. You don't need `runat="server"` anyway because your controls are dynamically generated and you won't need to access them that way.

Comment: I actually need to find out which values are checked when a button is clicked in the code behind, that's why I made the checkboxes runat the server.  Sorry, the sample is a little incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `runat="server"` already, I would recommend just using server-side controls to manage your dynamic content, like this:

```
<ul>
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" 
                  OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <asp:CheckBox id="check1" runat="server" />
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

Now when you bind the repeater (`OnItemDataBound`), you can access the `.Text` property of the checkbox, like this:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) 
{
    // This event is raised for the header, the footer, separators, and items.
    // Execute the following logic for Items and Alternating Items.
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) 
    {
        CheckBox theCheckBox = e.Item.FindControl("check1") as CheckBox;

        // Make sure we found the check box before we try to use it
        if(theCheckBox != null)
        {
            theCheckBox.Text = "Your Text Value Here";
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Using code-behind allows you to leverage the power of the Visual Studio debugger more easily and use IntelliSense to help reduce typos and catch more problems at compile-time versus run-time.

Comment: This looks promising except for the e.Item.FindControl("check1") as Checkbox; do I need to know the name of each control?  At this point I don't give each checkbox an ID because it's being generated dynamically.

Comment: Yes, I personally use javascript/jquery to handle my dynamic checkbox lists. You can use `ControlCollection CC = Repeater.Controls; foreach (RepeaterItem RI in CC)` and another `foreach` to get at every single Checkbox in your list, but identifying them will be a pain.

Comment: I'm going to see if I can't get this to work, thanks for the help guys :).

Answer (score -1):

[answer edited] Try setting testValue as below, using "&" and ".ToString()" for string concatenation:

```
<ul>
   <%
    string testValue = string.Empty;
    for(int index = 0; index < 5; index++)
    {
        testValue = "blah" & index.ToString();
     %>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" runat="server" value="<%=testValue %>" />
        </li>
    <%
    }
     %>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Craig I had "+", and changed them to "&" for string concatenation.

Comment: Hmm, if I try that, I get an error:  
Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error 
  Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

 Parser Error Message: Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.

Source Error: 

Line 13:              %>
Line 14:                 <li>
Line 15:                     <input type="checkbox" runat="server" value="<%=" & testValue + & %>"  />
Line 16:                 </li>
Line 17:             <%

Comment: Did you try it with my change, to "&"s?  If so, what's the error?

Comment: I did, the error is above, thanks for the help.  I had an extra '+' in the error above but I fixed it and still got the same error: value="<%= " & testValue & " %>"

Comment: My apologies:  input tag was actually correct.  Problem probably in string concatenation BEFORE value set... see edited answer now.

Comment: Added ".ToString()" to index, for concatenation.

Comment: Yeah, there was an issue with the concatenation, I just set it to testValue = "blah" and the output for value="<% testValue %>" generated the same result:  <input name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl00" type="checkbox" value="&lt;%= testValue %>" />

Comment: Put back the "=" you originally had, like value="<%=testValue %>" (I would not put a space between the "=" and "testValue")

Answer (score -1):

You can not do this, it look like PHP style. If you are using ASP.Net then you should change your code style completely

Comment: Of course you can use inline code. The codebehind file helps separate html and server code but you can always mix them for some unique results. [See this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/archive/2010/10/06/embedded-code-and-inline-server-tags.aspx) for an introduction.

Comment: you misunderstand me, I mean you can't with this scenario.